# Selenium with Ruby : Handling JS Prompt with 2 fields

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I want Selenium to connect to my Staging site, which is hosted on WPEngine. Therefore each time I connect, it asks me for a user name and password, in a Javascript prompt.

I can easily send text to the first (user name) field in the prompt :

```
def connectToStaging()
    alert = @browser.switch_to.alert
    if /username and password/.match(alert.text)
        alert.send_keys("username")
    end
end
```

But then I don't know how to switch to the password field to do the same.

I've tried sending a tab character right after sending the string "username" :

```
alert.send_keys(:tab)
```

But it returns an error : **NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for :tab:Symbol**

Otherwise I don't know if there's a way to target the field using **find_element** ? Or is there a function to switch to the next field in whatever window or form the pointer is in at the moment ?

Thanks so much !

Comment: try the approach [here](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/handle-authentication-popup-window/)

Comment: This solution works for me ! Thanks so much ! :-D

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: With max pleaner's solution above. Honestly it's been a long time and I haven't use my program since so I don't remember the exact steps I took, but it looks like I was able to fix my issue using their method in about 15 minutes so it must've been pretty intuitive...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @max-pleaner, a solution has been found.

[Documentation here](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/handle-authentication-popup-window/)

I chose the first solution proposed : you can authenticate by putting your credentials directly in the url : `https://username:password@www.yoursite.com`

Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Write this one

```
alert.send_keys("username",:tab,"password")
```

Comment: Gives me :

    Failure/Error: alert.send_keys("username",:tab,"password")
    ArgumentError:
        wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1)

Comment: @LeKevoid Since split method is being called, Can you try `"username :tab password"` Take out the , use space in that place. usually send_keys passes multiple keys but since it's called on alert, this may be the difference. Pass it by space rather than , I hope it would work.

Comment: Doesn't work either ; it just put the string "username :tab password" in the username field.
I also tried
`alert.send_keys("username" + :tab + "password")`
and it gave me **no implicit conversion of Symbol into String**